# Release terminal filestreams on start

Tags: init-file, start-up, config

I want emacs to release (instead of grabbing) the parent terminal when started through the command line. Better if it is possible to send error messages to some temporary file.

By that I mean something equivalent to `emacs 1>/dev/null 2>/tmp/emacs.xyz.log &`.

Is there a dedicated configuration option for this?